# Retrieval of the originating address (sender's number) by SMSC

Tags: sms, gsm, telecommunication

I'm trying to implement SMS transmission between two GSM devices. I've searched and read standards and articles a lot but couldn't find the answer to the following question. Does anyone know how does SMSC get aware of the sender's number and insert it in the TP-OA field of the SMS-Deliver packet stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'm not sure that either this is what you need or this would help you but anyways..

In *GSM* network there are a lot of nodes and each does certain things for which it is responsible. They communicate to each other with *messages*, that contain certain information needed for processing of required operation: establishing a call, sending SMS, doing Update Location etc.

So the information about sender's number comes to **SMSC** from another node called **VLR/MSC** together with a message saying to it *"Yo, one guy wants to send SMS to another guy. So here is this message and information about these guys. Please, forward it"*.

Here is scenario of **user A** sending SMS to **user B**:

1. **User A** sends SMS to **VLR/MSC** together with information about its destination
2. **VLR/MSC** then invokes *MAP* message *ForwardSM* (Forward Short Message) to send received data further through the network to a node called **SMS IMSC**

**SMS IMSC** is a node that plays a role of interface between network and **SMSC**

3. **SMS IMSC** on receipt of *ForwardSM* message sends *TPDU* (Transfer Protocol Data Unit) message towards **SMSC** with the text of sent SMS and routing information
4. After this **SMSC** sends reply to **user A** with a result of receiving the SMS. If it's successful then **SMSC** starts routing this SMS through the network towards **user B**

So the message you are looking for is *TPDU* message from **Point 3**. Type of this message is *SMS-SUBMIT* according to *TPDU* types.

**Edit**:

*Authentication* is separate operation that takes place when subscriber starts his activity (eg turns on his phone) or roams to another area that is being served by another **VLR/MSC**. Anyway, **VLR/MSC** treats this user as *new* to this area. Skip this part if you know what is **VLR/MSC**:

> **HLR** is a node that stores all the information about every subscriber in operator's network. So basically it's a *database* that has all the info about every single subscriber in the **entire** operator's network.
>
> And network covers huge geographical area so it's divided is smaller areas called *cells*. **VLR/MSC** is a node similar to **HLR** (it also stores subscribers' data). But it is responsible for one certain *cell*, so it stores data of subscribers who **currently** operate in this **certain cell**. So when new subscriber comes to its area **VLR/MSC** downloads his data from **HLR**. And when subscriber leaves this area **VLR/MSC** removes his data.
>
> And if some node would need to get subscriber's data, it won't "ask" **HLR** for it, but instead it will "ask" **VLR/MSC** in whose area the subscriber is currently active.

So when **VLR/MSC** sees a new subscriber coming to its area, before downloading his data from **HLR** it triggers *authentication* process to check if this user is valid and that someone else doesn't pretend to be this user:

1. **VLR/MSC** sends *Send Authentication Info* MAP message together with *IMSI* (mobile subscriber number which is uniquely identified by his SIM card) to **HLR**
2. **HLR** checks the given *IMSI* and validates subscriber. If subscriber exists and there is no troubles with him then **HLR** sends *IMSI* to **AUC** (Authentication Center)
3. On *IMSI* reception **AUC** generates a *triplet* (some encryption keys needed for subscriber identification) that contains *SRES*, *RAND* and *Kc* values and sends this data back to **HLR**
4. **HLR** forwards this data back to **VLR/MSC** which triggered *authentication* process
5. **VLR/MSC** after reception of *SRES*, *RAND* and *Kc* sends received *RAND* to mobile subscriber
6. After mobile subscriber receives the *RAND* he calculates *SRES* using given *RAND* and *Ki* (some value that is written in user's SIM card) and sends calculated *SRES* back to **VLR/MSC**
7. On the final step **VLR/MSC** compares *SRES* generated by **AUC** with *SRES* generated by user. And if they match then user is identified successfully, **VLR/MSC** fetches subscriber's data from **HLR** and *authentication* process is completed.

After **VLR/MSC** downloaded data from **HLR** every other node that would need data of this subscriber would fetch it from **VLR/MSC** not **HLR**. And after that *authentication* process won't start every time subscriber wants to do something (make a call, send SMS and so on).

So when **user A** sends SMS to **user B** the data about **user A** (his number for example) is stored in **VLR/MSC** *already* and it arrives to *SMSC* from **VLR/MSC** together with the SMS **user A** sent.

Comment: Hi ARtemachka! Thanks a lot for the time you took for answering me :)
This is more or less what I've been looking for. According to your answer, I'm assuming that the originating address is passed to the SMSC via VLR through authentication of the subscriber using the encryption keys stored in the SIM card. Am I right? :)

Comment: @Satan I edited my answer to give you info about what you asked. I tried to explain it as accessible as possible. So if you still have any questions don't hesitate :)

Comment: Hi ARtemachka! Thank you very much for your time and your answer :)
I believe I got what I've been seeking :)
It's so nice of you. In case of a question arising, I'd get back to you :)

Comment: Just a quick question, in bullet point number 1, how does VLR/MSC send _Send Authentication Info_ MAP message together with IMSI to HLR in the first place?

Comment: @Satan Could you please clarify your question? For me it's unclear what you mean by HOW it sends the message. What do you exactly want to know?

Comment: Sure! since the sender's number is not included in the PDU message that is sent to the SMSC from sender's mobile device, I'm trying to understand how SMSC gets aware of the sender's number when it receives an SMS-SUBMIT message. Because the sender's number is required to be inserted in the SMS-DELIVER PDU format by SMSC.

Comment: I think I've found my answer. It lies in the IMSI attach
 of GSM procedure :)